# How do you make a ComboBox CellFactory properly disable items on the fly?

Tags: java, javafx, combobox

I have several `ComboBox` that are used to pick a date and time for an appointment scheduler application, but when I customize the `CellFactory` it only properly disables the correct items the very first time you click and expand. Basically it should disable selections that allow you to select a date and time that is prior to `LocalDateTime.now()`. Here is a video showing the erratic behavior:  [https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=niGoIvVx9Y0](http://%20youtube.com/watch?v=niGoIvVx9Y0)

Here is the code for my cell factories:

```
startHour.setCellFactory((final ListView<String> param) -> {
        return new ComboBoxListCell<String>() {
            @Override
            public void updateItem(String item, boolean empty) {
                super.updateItem(item, empty);
                if(empty || item == null) {
                    setText(null);
                    setGraphic(null);
                } else {
                    LocalDateTime selected = createDateTime(startDate.getValue(), item,
                            startMinute.getValue(), startMeridian.getValue());
                    if(selected.isBefore(LocalDateTime.now())) {
                        System.out.print(item + ", ");
                        setDisable(true);
                        setStyle(COMBOCELL_DISABLED_COLOR);
                    }
                }
            }
        };
    });

    startMinute.setCellFactory((final ListView<String> listView) -> {
        return new ComboBoxListCell<String>() {
            @Override
            public void updateItem(String item, boolean empty) {
                super.updateItem(item, empty);
                if(empty || item == null) {
                    setText(null);
                    setGraphic(null);
                } else {
                    LocalDateTime selected = createDateTime(startDate.getValue(), startHour.getValue(),
                            item, startMeridian.getValue());
                    if(selected.isBefore(LocalDateTime.now())) {
                        setDisable(true);
                        setStyle(COMBOCELL_DISABLED_COLOR);
                    }
                }
            }
        };
    });

    startMeridian.setCellFactory((final ListView<String> listView) -> {
        return new ComboBoxListCell<String>() {
            @Override public void updateItem(String item, boolean empty) {
                super.updateItem(item, empty);
                if(empty || item == null) {
                    setText(null);
                    setGraphic(null);
                } else {
                    LocalDateTime selected = createDateTime(startDate.getValue(), startHour.getValue(),
                            startMinute.getValue(), item);
                    if(selected.isBefore(LocalDateTime.now())) {
                        setDisable(true);
                        setStyle(COMBOCELL_DISABLED_COLOR);
                    }
                }
            }
        };
    });
```

the selected `LocalDateTime` is calculated using this method:

```
private LocalDateTime createDateTime(LocalDate date, String hour, String minute, String meridian) {
    String dateTimeStr = date + " " + hour + " "  + minute + " " + meridian;
    return LocalDateTime.parse(dateTimeStr, DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd h m a"));
}
```

in `startHour#setCellFactory` I inserted a `println` statement showing the selected item converted into a `LocalDateTime` if it occured before `LocalDateTime.now()`, and this is the output I got:

> 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 12, 1, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 12, 12, 12, 1, 9, 12, 1, 9, 12, 2, 1, 7, 9,

The current time was 9:48AM and the selected time was 10:00AM, so the intended condition appears to be met. However, as the video shows, the behavior is very erratic AFTER expanding the `ComboBox` for the first time. I have similar cell factories for the `DatePicker` nodes and they work just fine.
Am I misunderstanding how `ComboBox#setCellFactory` is intended to be used?

Comment: Sorry, here is the vid link: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=niGoIvVx9Y0

Comment: From your code, I realize that you do nothing if the time `isAfter(LocalDateTime.now())` I.e., you may want to add an `else` to your `isBefore` check, to undo disabling of the cell.

Comment: Thanks, that helped with the random coloring and disabling of incorrect boxes when scrolling up and down, but it didn't solve the problem of items not re-enabling when the day is changed further into the future.

Comment: Without seeing more of your code, I want you to try changing the Date, and then select a different hour or minute and see if that updates correctly. My thinking is that the `CellFactory`s are not being called because they aren't being updated, only the `DatePicker` is being updated.

Comment: Yes, if I change the date, say to tomorrow, then open the hour combo box, it will correctly list all hours as selectable. Same for minutes and meridian. However, if I then change the date back to today, it will still show all hours as selectable, instead of showing hours that have already passed today as unselectable.

Comment: Yeah, I'm almost certain its because the `CellFactory`s aren't being called on a change of date. You may have to bind the properties so that when the `DatePicker` is changed, it will also change the others. Only thing I found that MAY help is a `dayCellFactoryProperty`. I'm also not sure this will work, as I don't have a test program to try it on. So best of luck.

Comment: So what I did was add a change listener to the DatePicker that manually sets the CellFactory again. Works like a charm.

Comment: @DayTripperID That's a bit of a hack, and you would also need to add similar change listeners to all the other relevant controls (`startHour`, `startMinute`), at which point is gets pretty convoluted. You should bind the disable property to a binding that depends on the relevant values.

Comment: I implemented your answer and it now works properly, no hacks needed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the `startHour`, you need the disabled state of the cell to (potentially) update when any of the cell's current item, the selected start date, the selected start minute, or the selected meridian change. You can do this with a binding.

(Note that you are using the wrong cell class. A `ComboBoxListCell` is for displaying an editable cell in a list that uses a combo box as the editor. You just need a plain `ListCell` here.)

```
startHour.setCellFactory((final ListView<String> param) -> {
    ListCell<String> cell = new ListCell<String>() {
        @Override
        public void updateItem(String item, boolean empty) {
            super.updateItem(item, empty);
            setText(item); // works in empty case as item will be null, as desired
        }
    };

    cell.disableProperty().bind(Bindings.createBooleanBinding(
        () -> {
            if (cell.getItem() == null) return false ;
            LocalDateTime selected = createDateTime(startDate.getValue(), cell.getItem(),
                        startMinute.getValue(), startMeridian.getValue());
            return selected.isBefore(LocalDateTime.now());
        }, 
        cell.itemProperty(), 
        startMinute.valueProperty(), 
        startMeridian.valueProperty(), 
        startDate.valueProperty()
    ));

    return cell ;
});
```

The other cell factories will be similar.

For the style, I strongly recommend you use an external style sheet, with a rule such as:

```css
.combo-box .list-cell:disabled {
    /* style for disabled cell here */
}
```

This keeps the code simpler, and means there is only one place to define the style for all the relevant disabled combo box cells.

Note that once a cell has been displayed that represents a time after the current time (so it is enabled), if it is displayed sufficiently later that it is no longer after the current time, then it won't be automatically disabled. (So, for example, if a cell representing 1pm on April 24th 2017 is first displayed at 12:55pm that day, it will be enabled. If it is displayed again 10 minutes later with no other UI changes that cause `updateItem()` to be called, it should be disabled, but will not be.) A complete solution would have the binding also observe the "current time" as it changes, for which you could do:

```
ObjectProperty<LocalDateTime> clock = new SimpleObjectProperty<>(LocalDateTime.now());
Timeline clockwork = new Timeline(new KeyFrame(Duration.seconds(1), 
        e -> clock.set(LocalDateTime.now())));
clockwork.setCycleCount(Animation.INDEFINITE);
clockwork.play();
```

and then add `clock` to the list of dependent values in the binding:

```
cell.disableProperty().bind(Bindings.createBooleanBinding(
    () -> {
        if (cell.getItem() == null) return false ;
        LocalDateTime selected = createDateTime(startDate.getValue(), cell.getItem(),
                    startMinute.getValue(), startMeridian.getValue());
        return selected.isBefore(clock.get());
    }, 
    cell.itemProperty(), 
    startMinute.valueProperty(), 
    startMeridian.valueProperty(), 
    startDate.valueProperty(),
    clock
));
```

Comment: I implemented this solution for all `ComboBox` instances on the starting line and everything now works as intended. Also separated the styling to an external CSS sheet. The binding was the solution.